# Spark coalesce relationship with number of executors and cores

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm bringing up a very silly question about Spark as I want to clear my confusion. I'm very new in Spark and still trying to understand how it works internally.

Say, if I have a list of input files(assume 1000) which I want to process or write somewhere and I want to use coalesce to reduce my partition number to 100.

Now I run this job with 12 executors with 5 cores per executor, that means 60 tasks when it runs. Does that mean, each of the task will work on one single partition independently?

> Round: 1   12 executors each with 5 cores => 60 tasks process 60
>   partitions
>   Round: 2   8 executors each with 5 cores => 40 tasks
>
> process the rest of the 40 partitions and 4 executors never place a
>   job for the 2nd time

Or all tasks from the same executor will work on the same partition?

> Round: 1:   12 executors => process 12 partitions
>   Round: 2:   12
>   executors => process 12 partitions
>   Round: 3:   12 executors =>
>   process 12 partitions
>   ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   Round: 9 (96 partitions
>   already processed):   4 executors => process the remaining 4
>   partitions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Say, if I have a list of input files(assume 1000) which I want to process or write somewhere and I want to use coalesce to reduce my partition number to 100.

In spark by default `number of partitions` = `hdfs blocks`, as `coalesce(100)` is specified, Spark will divide input data into 100 partitions.

> Now I run this job with 12 executors with 5 cores per executor, that means 60 tasks when it runs. Does that mean, each of the tasks will work on one single partition independently?

[image: Worker node with executors]

As you passed might be passed.

`--num-executors 12`: Number of executors to launch in an application.

`--executor-cores 5` : Number of cores per executor. **1 core = 1 task** at a time

So the execution of partitions will go like this.

#### Round 1

**12 partitions** will be processed by **12 executors with 5 tasks(threads)** each.

#### Round 2

**12 partitions** will be processed by **12 executors with 5 tasks(threads)** each.

.
.
.

#### Round: 9 (96 partitions already processed):

**4 partitions** will be processed by **4 executors with 5 tasks(threads)** each.

***NOTE:***
Usually, Some executors may complete assigned work quickly(various parameters like [data locality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006632/spark-hadoop-data-locality/40408454#40408454), Network I/O, CPU, etc.). So, it will pick the next partition to process by waiting for a configured amount of scheduling time.