# Processing single file on S3 using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, bigdata, emr

I have a single file located on S3 that I want to process using Spark using multiple nodes. How spark implements that under the hood? Does each of the worker node read a portion of data from S3 (using byte range request)? I'm trying to understand what are the differences between using Spark on HDFS and S3 in terms of parallel processing. Does it matter when I use EMR?

Answer (score 0):

> How spark implements that under the hood?

There are many public articles explaining how spark works like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777000/apache-spark-architecture?rq=1).

> I'm trying to understand what are the differences between using Spark on HDFS and S3 in terms of parallel processing. Does it matter when I use EMR?

It depends on what is your use case. In general, it boils down to :

- You would choose S3 over HDFS as a persistent storage option which can contain your data beyond your EMR cluster lifetime.
- Unlimited (theoretically) storage limit.
- High SLA and durability.
- Cost. HDFS on EMR is ephemeral. So you do not need to keep clusters running to have data available.
  [etc](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/top-5-reasons-for-choosing-s3-over-hdfs.html).

Vs

- HDFS is faster in I/O operations, intermediate/temporary data locations as S3 communication involves API calls over internet.