# From where does RDD loads data in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

From where does Spark load data for RDD? Is data already present in Executor nodes or spark shuffles data from Driver node first?

Answer (score 0):

From the name itself - RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset) - it indicates that the data resides across executors when ever you create it.

Lets say when you run `parallelize()` for 100 entries, it will distribute that 100 entries across your executors so that each executor has its own chunk of data to do distributed processing.

Shuffling happens - when you do any operations like `repartition()` or `coalesce()`.
Also if you run functions like `collect()` spark will try to pull all data from executor and bring it to driver(And you loose the ability of distributed processing)

This reference has more details around internals of spark - [Apache Spark architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777000/apache-spark-architecture)